# How to access .env variables with django-environ in travis ci?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, environment-variables, travis-ci

I'm trying to integrate travis ci with my django project using [django-environ](https://pypi.org/project/django-environ/) but i keep getting the same error in the travis ci build:

```
UserWarning: Error reading /home/travis/.../.env - if you're not configuring your environment separately, check this.

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable
```

Looks like django-environ can't find the environment variable.

I already tried exporting the `SECRET_KEY` variable through the .travis.yml file like this:
[.travis.yml config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0wvA.png).
But still does'nt seem to work.

Here's my .env file: [.env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk5A8.png)

And part of my settings.py: [settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3RJV.png)

I also tried setting the variable in the travis ci project configuration page.

---

### Edit: I found a workaround:

Since the variables were being set but for some reason the .env file wasnt being created (or the django-environ wasnt finding the variables), I created the file manually and set it to grab the variables previously added.

I did this in the `before_script` part of the .travis.yml file:

[image: .travis.yml]

It's not the best solution to the problem, but it's working and I didn't find another way to solve it. Hope this helps whoever also has this problem :)

Comment: Any updates here?